# need some advice with nav bar and my login button (html,css,js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a small project so I can learn web development but I'm kind of stuck at the beginning now. I made a navigation bar (doesn't work yet) and have buttons named like "home, play, login, donate" , so I have a form for my login button with username and password etc. I want to make it so when I press on the login button the form shows up in a small box and you can type in it, it doesn't have to work and by that I mean with PHP and such. Is there anywhere I could read more about this and learn or if someone could maybe show me an example and teaches me how to make it. Thanks would appreciate it !

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  position: :fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

form {
  border: 2px solid #111;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Game project</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/project001.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="play" href="#">Play</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a id="donate" href="#">Donate</a></li>
  </nav>

  <form>
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required><br>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required><br>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
  </form>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="project.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Sorry if you got the wrong idea but StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Try hiring a developer or trying it on your own before asking a question.

Comment: This is what I have done so far https://codepen.io/Vookie/pen/ZrGaZd

Comment: edit your question to include the relevant code. don't just add a link to the entire project

Comment: oh sorry, first time here on overstack, dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following snippet. I have used bootstrap navigation bar which you can refer in their document

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

And attached a modal to login button in the navigation bar.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Further more I have commented in the code for better understanding.

```html
<!--Insert bootstrap cdn to your html-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--Navigation bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    <!--Navigation items-->
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Play</a>
      <!--Insert a modal into login-->
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Login</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Donate</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--Modal-->
<!--Refering the data-target "exampleModal" in the nav bar-->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br><br>

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--Bootstrap 4 scripts-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Without bootstrap**

```js
/* This script supports IE9+ */
(function() {
  /* Opening modal window function */
  function openModal() {
    /* Get trigger element */
    var modalTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('jsModalTrigger');

    /* Set onclick event handler for all trigger elements */
    for (var i = 0; i < modalTrigger.length; i++) {
      modalTrigger[i].onclick = function() {
        var target = this.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
        var modalWindow = document.getElementById(target);

        modalWindow.classList ? modalWindow.classList.add('open') : modalWindow.className += ' ' + 'open';
      }
    }
  }

  function closeModal() {
    /* Get close button */
    var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('jsModalClose');
    var closeOverlay = document.getElementsByClassName('jsOverlay');

    /* Set onclick event handler for close buttons */
    for (var i = 0; i < closeButton.length; i++) {
      closeButton[i].onclick = function() {
        var modalWindow = this.parentNode.parentNode;

        modalWindow.classList ? modalWindow.classList.remove('open') : modalWindow.className = modalWindow.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + 'open'.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
      }
    }

    /* Set onclick event handler for modal overlay */
    for (var i = 0; i < closeOverlay.length; i++) {
      closeOverlay[i].onclick = function() {
        var modalWindow = this.parentNode;

        modalWindow.classList ? modalWindow.classList.remove('open') : modalWindow.className = modalWindow.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + 'open'.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
      }
    }

  }

  /* Handling domready event IE9+ */
  function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
      fn();
    } else {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
  }

  /* Triggering modal window function after dom ready */
  ready(openModal);
  ready(closeModal);
}());
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  position: :fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

form {
  border: 2px solid #111;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.1s, opacity 0.3s ease;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.1s, opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.modal.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 21;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #747474;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal__close:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.modal__container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 22;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Game project</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/project001.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="play" href="#">Play</a></li>
      <li style="float:right">
        <a id="popup" class="jsModalTrigger" href="#jsModal">Login</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a id="donate" href="#">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="jsModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal__overlay jsOverlay"></div>
    <div class="modal__container">
      <form>
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required><br>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required><br>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <button type="button">Cancel</button>
      </form>

      <button class="modal__close jsModalClose">&#10005;</button>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="project.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I dont want to use bootstrap, just normal html and css and js

Comment: There is another answer below without bootstrap. Check the snippet. Phew took a bit of time to do that

Comment: Please put a tick if this solves your issue as a small appreciation :) will give you points for completing this question as well

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciate it